# Summing by Department with conditional sum

Tags: crystal-reports

My income statement requires a column for each department in our business. Each of my six departments have their own Sales, Cost of Sales, Gross Profit, Overhead, and Net Income.

The view from the database contains columns for GL Number, Department Number, and Amount for every transaction. I can tell if its Sales, Cost of Sales, etc from the identifying GL Number. I am able to get all of the pertinent information from one view, however I don't know how to arrange it on the report.

I created an initial version in Excel using the Sumifs function. How can I get the same arrangement of data in Crystal Reports?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Running Totals** can be configured to only count records that meet given criteria. When creating the RT, select "sum" as the type of summary and "Use a Formula". In the "x-2" screen, write logic to filter out anything that doesn't meet the criteria you want.

Comment: Okay thank you.  I'll give that a try.  So would I need to summarize based on the Amount field and then put the formula in the Evaluate section?  And in the Reset section choose "On change of Field"?

Comment: I don't know - You never specified in your question what you were trying to sum. If you're looking for a grand total of, for example, all of Department 4's Amounts, you wouldn't ever Reset.

Comment: So basically I want to total up all Sales (which means all Amounts within a certain GL Account range) for Dept 1, then all Sales for Dept 2, then all Sales for Dept 3...

Comment: Then I'll have to do the same thing for Cost of Sales, Overhead, etc. which are all the Amounts within other GL ranges.

Comment: Sure. In that case, don't reset. It will be enough just to specify `Department = Dept 3` in the Use a Formula section.

Comment: Okay awesome. I'm getting the right numbers.  They just count up and then repeat hundreds of times. So I'm trying to figure that out.  Do I need to put them in a header instead?

Comment: I would recommend placing them in a footer. But that all depends on how your report is designed.

Comment: Okay many thanks!  I've got some formatting to figure out, but this is going the right direction.

Comment: What if my sum is a negative number and I need to switch the sign?

Comment: There's a few ways to handle that. You could Format the number to not use a sign. Or if that doesn't work, you could convert it to a String and remove the "-" character.

Comment: Okay thanks again.  One followup question and I'll figure out the rest.  I will wind up with a Sales sum and a Cost of Sales sum for each department.  Now how do you take those two figures and subtract one from the other to get a Gross Profit figure for each department?

Comment: I'd create Formula Fields. For example, GrossProfitDept4 would use the logic `{#RTsalesDept4} - {#RTcostOfSalesDept4}`

Comment: Awesome, I assumed it would be harder than that.  Thanks again.  You've helped me a ton!

Answer (score 0):

Simple way would be group by report by `GLNumber` and place all fields that required sum in details and insert summary in group footer.

Comment: Good idea as well.  Thank you!